# Select all images in the folder and save them in other folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I have a folder on my local machine that contains .jpeg files. I want to select all of these images and save them in the other folder. That is all. I am using c# and ASP.NET Webforms. Is there an easy way of doing so?

Thank you.

Comment: There is.. Have you looked at `File.Copy()` ?

Comment: Do you want just copy them in the destination folder or do you want to move them (IE Copy then Delete)? And more important. Are these source and destination folder under the root folder of your site?

Comment: No root folder. The starting folder and destination folder are on desktop of my local machine.  I was simply practicing for the bigger project at hand and had a little problem with selecting files. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var filesToCopy = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\path to images", "*.jpeg");

var directoryToCopyTo = "c:\destination folder";

foreach (var file in filesToCopy)
{
    File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(directoryToCopyTo, Path.GetFileName(file)));
}
```

Note: This **won't** copy images in sub-folders